# split year values in dax measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a simple measure called **COLORS** from my Fact Table and I have a Calendar table too.

Right now, when I select two different years from the slicer Calendar[YEAR] show wrong values (60 and 70)

| YEAR | RESULTS |
| --- | --- |
| 2020 | 60 |
| 2021 | 70 |

The measure I'm using is:

```
RESULTS = CALCULATE([COLORS], REMOVEFILTERS(Calendar, Calendar[YEAR]))
```

Same results with ALLEXEPT, KEEPFILTERS and HASONEFILTER

**BELOW MATRIX is correct**

| YEAR | RESULTS |
| --- | --- |
| 2020 | 30 |
| 2021 | 32 |

```
COLORS = DIVIDE([**TOTAL_MONEY**], [**TOTAL_VOLUME**])

TOTAL_MONEY =

VAR year = SELECTEDVALUE(Calendar[YEAR])
RETURN
CALCULATE([THE_MONEY],YEAR(Fact_Table[period]) = year && MONTH(Fact_Table[period]) IN DISTINCT(Calendar[Month]))
```

**TOTAL_VOLUME** is the same

modification of the measure :

```
RESULTS = CALCULATE([COLORS], REMOVEFILTERS(Calendar, Calendar[YEAR]))
```

with no results

Comment: Do you have a relationship between your Fact table and Date/Calendar table?

Comment: yes I do have a  relationship between the tables

Comment: Good, trying to understand what you are wanting. What are you trying to do with `TOTAL_MONEY`? Share what your data table looks like and what calculations or visualisation you are wanting.